# In C/C++ I want to write to the same pipe multiple times

Tags: c++, c, file-io, pipe, named-pipes

I have a program that creates pipes between two processes.  One process constantly monitors the output of the other and when specific output is encountered it gives input through the other pipe with the `write()` function.  The problem I am having, though is that the contents of the pipe don't go through to the other process's stdin stream until I `close()` the pipe.  I want this program to infinitely loop and react every time it encounters the output it is looking for.  Is there any way to send the input to the other process without closing the pipe?

I have searched a bit and found that named pipes can be reopened after closing them, but I wanted to find out if there was another option since I have already written the code to use unnamed pipes and I haven't yet learned to use named pipes.

Comment: How is the first process writing to the pipe? If it is uses `fprintf()`, etc, then perhaps its output is being buffered. A call to `fflush()` should push the data through.

Comment: It is writing to the pipe with a line that looks something like `write(pipe[1], string, strlen(string));`. `fflush()` looks promising, I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you reading the other end? Are you expecting complete strings? You aren't sending terminating NULs in the snippet you posted. Perhaps sending strlen(string)+1 bytes will fix it.  Without seeing the code it's hard to tell.

Comment: The other end of the pipe is going into the `stdin` stream of a program that I don't have the source code for. So basically I'm creating the pipes, forking a new process, in the child process I'm using `dup2` to connect the pipes to `stdin` and `stdout`.  I will try your suggestions and report back on my findings, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thank you so much, your suggestion got me most of the way toward the answer to my problem.  The input was going to a sort of command line, so my problem was that I wasn't using a newline character at the end to simulate pressing the enter key to submit the command.

Comment: What snippet is referred to?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at using [fflush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fflush).

Comment: I read a little bit and are you sure you can use `fflush` on a pipe?  The problem is that the input gets pushed into the pipe's buffer and then just sits there instead of being sent to the second process's stdin. if I use `write(pipe[1],str,strlen(str)); close(pipe[1]);` the input will be sent, but I can't seem to find any other way to make it send.  `pipe[1]` is an `integer`, and fflush takes a `FILE *` as an argument, I'm not sure how to make use of that.

Comment: @Alex: If I remember correctly the integer is a file descriptor and you can open it using fdopen.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650468/how-can-i-use-fprintf-and-write-to-a-pipe   This can be quite convenient if you ever want to use things like fprintf with the pipe.

Comment: I tried that out and it compiles using fdopen, but it still isn't pushing the input through to the child process.

Comment: @Alex:  I am not sure then maybe there's something else going on in your code.

Comment: well, the way I am trying to do it now is `write(pipe[1],str,strlen(str)); fflush(fdopen(pipe[1],"w");` does this seem right or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You are misunderstanding. `fflush()` won't matter if you are writing via `write`. Only `fwrite`s are flushed by an `fflush`.

Answer (score 1):

Use fsync. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/fsync.html

From http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_239.html:
Once write returns, the data is enqueued to be written and can be read back right away, but it is not necessarily written out to permanent storage immediately. You can use fsync when you need to be sure your data has been permanently stored before continuing. (It is more efficient for the system to batch up consecutive writes and do them all at once when convenient. Normally they will always be written to disk within a minute or less.) Modern systems provide another function fdatasync which guarantees integrity only for the file data and is therefore faster. You can use the O_FSYNC open mode to make write always store the data to disk before returning.